What do we call a subgraph containing all directed paths from one vertex to another?
Let $\mathcal{G} = (\mathcal{V}, \mathcal{E})$ be a directed graph. For two distinct vertices $i,j \in \mathcal{V}$, the subgraph $\mathcal{G}_{i,j}$ contains all directed paths from $i$ to $j$.
My question is, what do we call such a subgraph $\mathcal{G}_{i,j}$? Thanks so much!
PS: For an undirected graph, such a subgraph is called a connected component. There is a related concept -- the strongly connected component. However, it describes a subgraph that is strongly connected, which is different from the subgraph in this question.

In category theory, this is called a full subcategory so I would consider calling it a full subgraph.

@SammyBlack Thanks very much! The full subgraph is a good name, and I think we can call it a full subgraph from $i$ to $j$.

Full subgraph in category theory is a synonym for induced subgraph: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/graph#fnref:5. I would call this the subgraph of induced paths from $i$ to $j$ since there already is terminology related to induced paths like the induced path number or path cover number.

@RandyMarsh Thanks very much for your answer! Yes, it is an induced subgraph whose vertices are $i$, $j$, and all nodes related to all paths from $i$ to $j$. For an undirected graph, it is a connected component containing $i$ and $j$. For directed graphs, the subgraph of induced paths from $i$ to $j$ can accurately describe this situation. So, how about "Path-Induced Subgraph From Vertices $i$ to $j$" or simply "Path-Induced Subgraph From $i$ to $j$"? I think the name would be more concise.

Yes, that does sound more concise and immediately communicates what the object is about.

It's really surprising to me that there doesn't seem to be a standard term for this. Maybe it's not so useful theoretically, but in practical applications this concept surely will pop up often?

@olejorgenb Thanks very much for your comments. This concept is very useful in my current research on distributed estimation and control.
